# Many to one Relationship with inherited Classes

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning Flask and currently building an address book application with. When implementing my Model with SQLAlchemy I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Company.contacts - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.relationship('Address',
                              secondary=address_person,
                              backref=db.backref('persons', lazy='dynamic'),
                              lazy='dynamic')
    projects = db.relationship('Project',
                               secondary="project_person_link",
                               backref=db.backref('persons', lazy='dynamic'),
                               lazy='dynamic')
    phonenumbers = db.relationship('Phone', backref='Phonenumbers', lazy='dynamic')
    mails = db.relationship('Mail', backref='Mails', lazy='dynamic')


class Company(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    name = db.Column(db.String(250))
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))

    contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref="company", lazy='dynamic')


class Contact(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    name = db.Column(db.String(250))
    christmas_card = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    picture = db.Column(db.String(250))

    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
```

I'm not really seeing what I did wrong and would be helpful for any hint.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you actually want to inherit from `Person` here. Unless a `Company` is a `Person`, you'll want to inherit from `db.Model` instead.

Comment: Actually I do. A company is a juristic person and a contact a real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by including a primaryjoin argument.

```
class Company(Person):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    name = db.Column(db.String(250))
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))

    contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref="company", primaryjoin="Company.id==Contact.company_id")
```

Comment: Can you create a company without creating a Person with this code? I tried it but I couldn't create a Company with an already existing Person